# Window.open throw and error "2147417851 ' --> "The server threw an exception" when the main thread is busy

Tags: javascript, activex

I am using the below code to open a new window :

```
 function WindowOpen() {
    try {
        var newWindow = window.open('test.html', "DUMMY", "resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,top=0,left=0,width=500,height=500");
        newWindow.focus();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert("Exeception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

test.html is opening an active X control.

**Issue:**

When test.html open the active x control, it block the container(test.html).Now when I call "WindowOpen" , it throws the below exception on second call if I call subsequently(clicking link multiple time)

**2147417851 ' --> "The server threw an exception**

Apologize if I not able to convey the question.